# Add Total and Average columns in Power BI matrix

Tags: powerbi, dax, analytics, powerbi-desktop, dashboard

I am trying to add average and sum column to power BI matrix
the result is categorized and displayed below each month as shown in the below

[image]

but the result I want is such as

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a way to do this. You could go into Visual properties > Column headers > Options > and switch off `Auto-size width` and just above switch off `Text wrap. Then for each month, resize the Avg column to as little as possible.

Comment: @SamNseir - this is known as an asymmetric matrix. It can be done but needs quite a bit of set up. e.g. https://exceleratorbi.com.au/building-a-matrix-with-asymmetrical-columns-and-rows-in-power-bi/

Comment: @DavideBacci - you are correct, it can be done 